# javafx(canvas) cut text to a custom length to fit in a rect

Tags: canvas, javafx, graphics

I'm using

```
gc.fillText(text, x, y);
```

to draw a text on a rect. If the text is too long for the rect it should being cutted at the end.

I've tried

```
gc.fillText(text, x, y, maxwidth);
```

but the text is just shrinking and disappearing when much too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`clip`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#clip--) to restrict the area where the text is being drawn by the last path (note that the text's y 0 is located at the base line):

```
private boolean clip;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(500, 500);

    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(canvas));

    draw(canvas, clip = !clip);
    scene.setOnMouseClicked(evt -> draw(canvas, clip = !clip));

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

private static void draw(Canvas canvas, boolean clip) {
    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    gc.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    gc.save();
    if (clip) {
        // draw clipping rect
        gc.rect(100, 50, 300, 300);
        gc.clip();
    }

    String text = "aonrjis  rnsrns jnrs inrs no rsnors nojrsnon rgsn rsön rgsn rsunrs nui rsni rsnrs no naoi reosn s";
    gc.fillText(text, 100, 100);
    gc.restore();
}
```

You can toggle between clipped and non-clipped by clicking on the scene in this example.